# Android seems to not always execute my function

Tags: android, profiling, ddms

here is my problem : the following code is running from a thread created by my main application :

```
for (i = 0; i < nbiter; i++)
{
 call to Method_A()
}
```

Method_A() is :

```
for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
{
...
call to Method_B()
..
}
```

Method_B is doing 6 multiplications using BigInteger class.

Now when i run the program with nbiter set to 1, i see using DDMS profiler that there is 256 calls to method_B.
But when nbiter is set to 2, sometimes there are 277 calls to method_B, sometimes 330 or 333 .... but no 512 calls .
Anyone has an idea ???
Thanks.

Here is the code of Method_A() :

```
public Point Method_A(byte[] eac, Point PhiP, int cpt)
    {
        int j;

        for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {
            if (eac[j] == 0)
                PQ = PhiP.ZADDU(this);
            else
                PQ = this.ZADDU(PhiP);
            this.X = PQ[0];
            this.Y = PQ[1] ;
            PhiP.X = PQ[2] ;
            PhiP.Y = PQ[3] ;
            this.Z = PQ[4] ;
            PhiP.Z = PQ[4] ;
            Log.d("MULT",cpt+":"+j);
        }
        this.X = PQ[0];
        this.Y = PQ[1] ;
        PhiP.X = PQ[2] ;
        PhiP.Y = PQ[3] ;
        this.Z = PQ[4] ;
        PhiP.Z = PQ[4] ;
        return new Point(PQ[2],PQ[3],PQ[4],a,b,p);
    }

}
```

I call Method_A() with counter i as third variable and in the logcat windows i have (with nbiter set to 2)
0:0
0:1
..
0:255
1:0
1:1
..
1:255

Comment: post the full code for Method_A(). What is "..."? Is it possible that Method_A is returning prematurely, or breaking out of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that since you have put i=0 instead of int i=0 in the code you have posted for the for loops, this is what you also have in your project. In that case 'i' & 'j', the variables in your for loops, aren't initialised in the loops, so are you setting them to zero after the loop?

if you do

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbiter; i++)
{
 call to Method_A()
}
```

then at least you don't have to worry about 'i' holding a non-zero value next time the loop is called

Comment: i don't understand your comment. The main loop (variable i) runs one time for i from 0 to nbiter-1 , variable i has been declared in the main class (int i). For each value of "i", the inner loop is executed and each time "j" begins with value 0.

Comment: Fair enough.  I would log the value of 'i' each time before method A, and the value of 'j' before method B and then you can see what values the loops are running through.

Comment: as you can see there is a Log.d instruction in the code which outputs the value of j and the parameter cpt which corresponds to "i" when i call method_A(,,i) and the output is 0:0 0:1 ... 0:255 1:0 1:1 ... 1:255 . So the two loops are entirely executed

Comment: Then your question seems moot.  According to the question method b is being called 277, 330 or 333 times and not 512 times.  But if the Log.d within method b is logging 512 times obviously the method is being called and the problem is that sometimes it does not output as you expect.

Comment: i agree with you, but the profiler included in Android studio tells me that there were only 333/333 calls to the method .... That's very strange !